# in a Dataset column amount mention in abbreviated Million & Billion how to remove and calculate mean of this column

Tags: r

IN data set column "revenue" numeric value mention in $sign and abbreviated Million and Billion form. How to calculate mean value of "Revenue"

```
enter code here
 B_l$revenue<-split(B_l$revenue, split="M", Split="B")/1000
```

Comment: mention code is not work and through error

Comment: error : formal argument  split matched by multiple actual argument

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use `sub` to remove the "B|M" with `sub` and calculate the `mean` of the column

```
mean(as.numeric(sub("B|M", "", B_l$revenue)), na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or using `parse_number` to extract the numeric part and then get the `mean`

```
library(readr)
mean(parse_number(B_l$revenue), na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

It is not clear about the division.  If the 'B' elements should be divided by 1000

```
i1 <- grepl("B", B_l$revenue)
v1 <- parse_number(B_l$revenue)
v1[i1] <- v1[i1]/1000
mean(v1)
```